# Opencv not installing on Raspberry Pi 1 B+

Tags: python, git, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi

No matter what I do I can't install opencv on my RPi. I keep running out of memory and can't find a solution.

I've tried:

```
sudo pip install opencv-python
sudo pip install opencv-python --no-cache-dir
```

The first got killed (out of memory) and the second failed with error code 2 in None (although it didn't run out of memory).

I've tried making a 2gb swap file but to no avail (I got a similar error to when I ran sudo pip install opencv-python --no-cache-dir)

I also tried to install it with git. I have the unpacked opencv folder on my RPi but there is no make file (that I can find) and I don't know how I would build it.

My current theory is that my raspberry pi is simply too old. It's a raspberry pi 1 b+ which I found in my closet. It has 1gb of ram but it's from 2014 so the ram may be simply too slow. I really don't want to drop another $1xx on a brand new RPi when my current one works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: wait, so the install itself runs out of memory? uhhh what else is using ram, how much ram do you have for applications vs graphics/GPU? -- don't buy raspberry pi. they only sell to big companies, not to hobbyists. there are alternatives. all the other fruit "pis", and odroid.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi 1 B+ with 1GB of RAM? That seems a bit odd...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Basically nothing else is using ram. Also I look at alternatives but can't find any with a csi 2 port for a camera (integral to my project). I've looked at odroids, orange pis, banana pis, potato pis, and libre computers but maybe I'm just not looking hard enough. Any suggestions that have a csi 2 port?

Comment: @DanMašek yeah it's weird. The specsheet says it should have 512mb of ram but task manager says I have like 900 or something.

Answer (score 0):

The [Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Model_comparison) should come with 512 MB of RAM. If your system's task manager is showing more than this, it's likely because it's also including the swap space.

Swap space is a portion of your storage (SD card in the case of a Raspberry Pi) that the system uses as if it were RAM, when the physical RAM gets full. However, swap space is much slower than actual RAM because it's essentially just storage space.

Check what [`free -h`](https://linuxize.com/post/free-command-in-linux/) (or `sudo free -h`) tells you. It should display the amount of free and used memory in your system, including swap space.